# How to work install MWS library in Java, Maven based project?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-mws, fishbowl

It's the first time I am trying to use MWS library with `Java`. I have small `Spring Boot` application `Maven`-based. I wanted to install `mws` from https://mvnrepository.com/ by `mws` I found several libraries located on `Fishbowldev`. At the time of writing this post, repo seems to be unavailable. Example of [library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/amazon/mws-orders/2013-09-01-2015-09-25) I wanted to use.

At the moment, my `pom.xml` looks the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.test.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>fishbowldev</id>
            <name>Fishbowldev Repository</name>
            <url>http://murky.fishbowldev.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MWS libraries -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/amazon/mws-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>amazon</groupId>
            <artifactId>mws-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/amazon/mws-sellers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>amazon</groupId>
            <artifactId>mws-sellers</artifactId>
            <version>2011-07-01</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/amazon/mws-orders -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>amazon</groupId>
            <artifactId>mws-orders</artifactId>
            <version>2013-09-01-2015-09-25</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there any other way except of manual installation to add this library to my `pom.xml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any exact solution for my question. Instead I found a workaround. The project that `Mavenised` the old `MWS Java SDK` on [GitHub](https://github.com/trifonnt/ext-lib-amazon-mws-products).

The solution doesn't create any fancy way of working with `MWS` it is just a convenient wrapper for `Maven`-based projects.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Configure the `maven-install-plugin` with the goal `install-file` in your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-external-non-maven-jar-MWS-Client-into-local-maven-repo</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>com.amazonservices.mws</groupId>
                <artifactId>mws-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <file>${project.basedir}/lib/MWSClientJavaRuntime-1.0.jar</file>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Make sure to edit the `file` path based on your actual file path (recommended is to place these external non-maven jars inside some folder, let's say `lib`, and place this `lib` folder inside your project so as to use project-specific relative path and avoid adding system specific absolute path.

**Step 2:** Once you have configured the `maven-install-plugin` as shown above in your `pom.xml` file, you have to use these jars in your `pom.xml` as usual:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonservices.mws</groupId>
        <artifactId>mws-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note that the `maven-install-plugin` only copies your external jars to your local `.m2` maven repository. That's it. It doesn't automatically include these jars as maven dependencies to your project.

It's a minor point, but sometimes easy to miss.